# map multiple properties in array of objects to the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}]
```

and I want to map the `a` and `b` properties to a single array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] //single array with a and b together
```

I could do this:

```
[...objArray.map(d => d.a), ...objArray.map(d => d.b)]
```

However I want to avoid looping through the `objArray` multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map over the `objArray` to get the values, but then you end up with a nested array like so: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`. Use `apply` to pass the nested arrays as attributes to `concat` to concatenate into a single array.

```js
var objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}];
var reducedArray = [].concat.apply([], objArray.map(Object.values));
console.log(reducedArray);
```

Or with ES6, you can use the spread operator `...` instead of passing an array of attributes to concat, and then you don't need to use `apply`, because the spread operator will spread out the nested arrays into individual properties.

```js
const objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}];
const reducedArray = [].concat(...objArray.map(Object.values));
console.log(reducedArray);
```

`Object.values` will allow the `map` function to work on an arbitrary number of values. Thanks to [Nina Scholz in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43454841/228429) for the `Object.values` idea.

Note: both methods only work for arrays nested a single level deep.

Comment: Adding Object.values to what I had originally was a good idea, seemed good to edit this answer to incorporate it. Thanks! I made sure to give credit.

Comment: you may think about an upvote, because my answer is so good, that you incorporate it in your answer. i feel exploited.

Comment: Editing answers to make them better is not exploitation, it helps the entire ecosystem. Notice I did give credit to you for the one piece I edited. I did not downvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}];
var newArray = [];
objArray.forEach(function(obj) {
  newArray.push(obj.a, obj.b);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my favourite array iterator `array.reduce()`.

It accepts an "Accumulator" value, and an iteration function that will be invoked for each item in the array. In the function you can amend the accumulator using the array item.

So for your case, you can make the accumulator an empty array `[]`, and push the item's `a` and `b` properties...

```
var objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}];

var result = objArray.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  acc.push(obj.a);
  acc.push(obj.b);

  return acc;
}, []);
```

or with ES6

```
var objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}];

var result = objArray.reduce((acc, { a, b }) => [ ...acc, a, b ]), []);
```

For more info see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for an arbitrary number of properties.

```js
var objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}],
    result = [].concat(...objArray.map(Object.values));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a reusable generator function as follows:

```js
// Flatten objects to their values:
function* flatten(objects) {
  for (let obj of objects) yield* Object.values(obj);
}

// Example:
let objects = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}];
console.log([...flatten(objects)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for a variety;

```js
var objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4, c: 7}, {a: 5, b: 6}],
    flatObj  = a => a.length ? Object.values(a[0]).concat(flatObj(a.slice(1))) : [];
console.log(flatObj(objArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow danbahrami's code but potentially add a filter in the event that objects may not contain either a or b.

```js
var objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, c: 6}];
var result = objArray.reduce((acc, { a, b }) => [ ...acc, a, b ], []).filter(i => i);
console.log(result)
```